# controlling ABNewPersonViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, abpersonviewcontroller, abperson

I'm using `ABNewPersonViewController` to add a new contact. However, I want to ensure that the user inputs some fields. How do I achieve this?

I don't see any help from `ABNewPersonControllerDelegate` or from `ABNewPersonViewController`.

Comment: if( field.text == @"") ?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I check this in the delegate method? And if it doesn't match my criteria then don't allow to dismiss the controller ?

Comment: You need add yourTextFiled.delegate = self. after that, catch delegate  textFieldShouldBeginEditing or textFieldDidBeginEditing. When user presses OK button, let check condition: if(username.text.length>0) etc.

Comment: @Watsche You can't use `== @""` to see if an `NSString` is the empty string.

Comment: @nmh What text field? The question is about creating a new contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only real choice is to implement the `ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate` delegate method `newPersonViewController:didCompleteWithNewPerson:`. You will be given the `ABRecordRef` of the new contact. You will then need to load that contact and see if there are values. If not, you can choose to delete the new contact.

Comment: I don't see any other alternative.